# how to keep alignment while moving elements

Tags: jquery, justify

```js
$('.box').on('click', function(){
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
$('.act').insertAfter($('.act').next());
});
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:justify;
background:lightgreen;
}

.box{
display:inline-block;
width:20%;
height:25px;
background:orange;
}

.act{
background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='box'>1</div>
<div class='box'>1</div>
<div class='box'>1</div>
<div class='box'>1</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Click on the first box to make it active.

Then click on the button to move it right.

You see that alignment is lost, i.e. there is no spaces between boxes.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `insertAfterafter`, which will mess up the `justify` style, just switch the location between the divs:

```js
$('.box').on('click', function(){
$('.act').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){

    div1 = $('.act');
    div2 = $('.act').next();

    tdiv1 = div1.clone();
    tdiv2 = div2.clone();

    if(!div2.is(':empty')){
        div1.replaceWith(tdiv2);
        div2.replaceWith(tdiv1);

        $('.box').on('click', function(){
            $('.act').removeClass('act');
            $(this).addClass('act');
        });
    }
//   $('.act').insertAfter($('.act').next());
});
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:justify;
background:lightgreen;
}

.box{
display:inline-block;
width:20%;
height:25px;
background:orange;
}

.act{
background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='box'>1</div>
<div class='box'>2</div>
<div class='box'>3</div>
<div class='box'>4</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, but I will keep the post open to see if there is maybe more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the same way the previous answer is done, i.e by cloning and switching between the elements. But in the prev. answer the elements are getting disappeared after couple of clicks.

I've handled the condition when `.next()` is not available, hence having siblings elements looped.

```
$('.box').on('click', function (){
  $('.act').removeClass('act');
  $(this).addClass('act');
});

$('button').on('click', function (){ 
  if($('.act').length > 0)
  {
    activeBox = $('.act');
    nextBox = $('.act').next('.box').length > 0 ? $('.act').next('.box') : $('.box').eq(0);

    cloneActiveBox = activeBox.clone();
    cloneNextBox = nextBox.clone(); 

    activeBox.replaceWith(cloneNextBox);
    nextBox.replaceWith(cloneActiveBox); 

    $('.box').on('click', function (){
      $('.act').removeClass('act');
      $(this).addClass('act');
    });    
  } 
});
```

Link to the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43psy50b/2/